# C++ lambda expression does not compile

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, lambda

I am trying to `cin` a loop index's value in the loop itself using lambda expression:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  for(int a, ([](int & b){cin>>b;})(a); a < 2; ++a);
  return 0;
}
```

These are the errors when i compile using g++ 4.5 on ubuntu:

```
forLoopAndCinTest.c++: In function ‘int main()’:
forLoopAndCinTest.c++:5:14: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
forLoopAndCinTest.c++:5:14: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘[’ token
forLoopAndCinTest.c++:5:34: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
forLoopAndCinTest.c++:5:34: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
forLoopAndCinTest.c++:5:40: error: name lookup of ‘a’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping
forLoopAndCinTest.c++:5:40: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
forLoopAndCinTest.c++:5:50: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
```

If i use a normal function instead of the lambda, program compiles fine.
 Using -fpermissive doesnt help either.
 Any ideas?

Comment: The current C++ standard doesn't have lambda expressions, so have you specified the option to enable C++0x support?

Comment: Oh yes Steve. I do use -std=C++0x flag when compiling. Plus, g++ complains if the flag is not used.

Comment: I dont think you capture variables in (). [] is used to capture variables. () is used to pass parameters to the lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how the `for` look works. You are trying to call a lambda where the compiler expects you to declare an `int`:

```
for( int a, int2, ...; a < 2; ++a );
```

Now,

> If i use a normal function instead of
>   the lambda, program compiles fine

Yes, but it's probably not doing what you think it does.

```
void f(int& b)
{
    cin >> b;
}

// ...
for( int a, f(a); a < 2; ++a );
```

Here, the loop declares two *`int`* variables, named `a` and `f`. The loop doesn't call `f()` as you might expect.

Try this instead:

```
for( int a; cin >> a && a < 2; ++a );
```

Comment: I did not understand how the loop 'thinks' that a and f are variables and why f() isnt called. If it is not called, how is the cin statement executed? Thank you for the last idiom.

Comment: Got it. It doesnt execute the function at all. It just declares a variable with the appropriate type.

Comment: By the way i got what i wanted: for(int a, x = (cin >> a && 1); a < 10; ++a). Scans the variable inside the for loop although has to use an extra variable and the && operation. But cool. :)

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the *for* is interpreted as a declaration. We get the very same error when replacing your code by the (almost) equivalent :

```
int main(){
    int a, ([](int & b){cin>>b;})(a); // This produces the same error
    for(; a < 2; ++a);
    return 0;
}
```

To answer a comment you made, `for (int a, foo() ; ...` works, but not like you think it does. It is in fact declaring a function (inside the for scope) that returns an int, and has the name *foo*. As in :

```
int a, foo();
```

Which you should read as :

```
int a;
int foo();
```

Comment: All this is to avoid the cin outside the loop. Yes, this will definitely work. But i still dont understand why i can call any normal function in the declaration part but not lambda.

Comment: You can't. When you write `for (int a, foo() ; a<2 ; a++)` you are NOT calling the foo function. (Try it for yourself).

Answer (score 0):

After this: `for( int a,` compiler expects some name (of the variable) - unqualified-id. 
But in your case it is not so.

Comment: Yeah, it is just an expression list so your declaration should work either. Interesting.